# Windows 2003/IIS6 - Unexpected Error: C0000005

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

Our event logs are full of these errors

Unexpected error. A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.

We have tried in various ways but could not stop this error. After continuous errors, the IIS hangs up.

We are also getting another error, Warning: IIS log failed to write entry. Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that's a COM object failing and ASP catching it.  [iisstate](http://www.iisfaq.com/default.aspx?view=P197) can help you catch the culprit.  It will give you a log of what's going on and where the error is.

```
iisstate -p <pid of process hosting ASP pages> -sc <enter>
```

As for your other error, is anonymous access allowed on the website in question?  Whoever is generating the error doesn't have permission to write to the event log, which could be as simple as IUSR_ComputerName needing access.  Or it could be much trickier.  I'd need some more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas. I will try your suggestion and update the status.

Comment: I have used iisstate and found the culprit! It is some third party ASP.NET application we are using causing the problem. We also needed to use WinDBG to trace this out. Thanks for the help Thomas. We have also separated the Application Pools for different Applications.